# Configuring Simple2D graphics library in Windows

Tags: c, graphics

rookie here .. I have always struggled configuring a graphics library to actually work .. been coding in C for last two months using the stoneage WINBGIM lib, so in search for a little modern graphic lib I found Simple2D. I followed the documentation as straight as I could, but im having troubles. So it would be great, great help if any of you could look into it, thank you.

- $ simple2d build triangle.c
- /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingw32
- collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[link for the library](https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d)

Comment: please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: The error says you are missing the library mingw32 or else the path to the library is not set correctly.  My guess is you installed the 64-bit tools, but are trying to build in 32-bit mode.